# Error in DB2 on z/OS revoke

Tags: db2, zos

I am observing weird behavior with db2 z/OS revoke operation.

Suppose I create a user, assign some privileges and try to drop a user or if I try to revoke some privileges, I get error
"DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-556, SQLSTATE=42504, SQLERRMC=USER3;CREATETAB; ON DSN00016;TESTJDBC, DRIVER=3.67.28"
As per the error code, it means "Cannot revoke a privilege that the user does not possess".

But I see that privilege assigned to an user.

And if assign same privilege and then if try revoking it successfully revokes.

Help me with this

Comment: Posting the actual statements that you ran might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else granted the privilege, then DB2 may be complaining that you weren't the grantor.  You might try adding `BY <other_grantor>`, or just `BY ALL` to the end of your `REVOKE`.

[Here'](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_revoke.dita)s the relevant snippet from Knowledge Center:

> If the BY clause is not specified, the authorization ID of the
>   statement must have granted at least one of the specified privileges
>   to every *authorization-name* specified in the FROM clause (including
>   PUBLIC, if specified). If the BY clause is specified, the
>   authorization ID of the statement must have **SECADM** or
>   **ACCESSCTRL** authority.